# Best Pyspark Testing : issue with databricks -connect

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pytest, databricks, databricks-connect

I'm currently using databricks and in order to test my databricks code I'm using databricks connect in VS code. While I'm using databricks connect, since yesterday suddenly it started behaving strange, while I'm submitting a code from VS Code, the databricks-connect is taking the access of the person who has created the databricks cluster, now he doesn't have adequate access over all the resources and my test cases/ code is failing due to access issue.

Some more inputs: I have a function which does an update operation in a delta table, so this means i can't use a normal hive or temp table as they doesn't support update operation.

I have tried delta-lake in local, but that seems tobe not working and also not that convenient, as i wouldn't be able to access my ADLs location (until i specifically do the configuration change)
So, mu question is , how you guys are doing a spark specific testing? (I'm using pytest).
I found we don't have much material for a databricks code testing in the internet..any help?